# Check box is not shown as unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

I tried the following in my Angular app :

```
$(document).on('click touchend', '.dropdown-menu', function(e) {
    console.log("Inside....click on");
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("stop..prop");
});
```

and still my checkbox is not showing unchecked mark even if the ng-model value is set to false properly. What might be the reason?

MY HTML:

```
function clearAll() {
    for (var i = 0; i < vm.list.length; i++) {
        if (vm.list[i].flag === true) {
            vm.list[i].flag = false;
            vm.listFilterCount -= (vm.list[i].value.length + 3);
        }
    }

    vm.listFilterS = '';
    vm.count= ' ';
    vm.include= [];
    vm.list= [];
}


<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 borderAtRight" 

    <!--  Dropdown and Menu -->
    <div class="btn-group topFilterCtrl filterDropdn" dropdown dropdown-append-to-body id="ddlStatus">
    <div id="btn-append-to-body" type="button" class="btn btn-primary panelTextFont14 noBorder" dropdown-toggle> Status 
        <span class="caret caretSpan"></span>
    </div>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropDownLabel" role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-append-to-body" ng-show="!vm.showthis">
    <div class="customScroll">
        <li role="menuitem" class="changeColorOnHover" ng-repeat="optionThis in vm.List track by $index" ng-show="list.value != null">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="checkbox" id="{index}" ng-show="this.value != null" ng-click="vm.applyFilterForResultCount()" ng-change="vm.getCount(this)" ng-model="this.flag">
                    <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-click="vm.clickStatusCheckBox(this);$event.stopPropagation();" ng-show="this.value != null" />
                {{this.value}}
            </label>
            </div>
        </a>
        </li>
    </div>
        <!--Clear div-->
        <li role="menuitem" class="btn btn-default buttonli" ng-click="vm.clearAll()">
        <a href="#">
                <p>
                    <span class="clearAllBtn">Clear</span>
                <span class="dropDownBtnItem">  – All </span>
            </p>
        </a>
    </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Screenshot of problem:

[image]

Comment: There is a lot missing code here, can you create a jsfiddle? I don't see an `ng-model` on your checkbox, so why would it change according to an angular value?

Comment: maybe typo here ? : `id="{}index}"`

Comment: This is a typo in posting. I have it right in my actual code. Also, ng-model -this.flag is set to false properly. Only unchcek is not shown instead checkbox always has right tick mark on clear button click

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle, the problem is still unclear

Comment: Since I have dynamic data, I can not create a fiddle. Problem is on click of clear button, the check box should get unchecked. But its still shown checked as seen in screenshot